# Can I double tap with a .44 magnum in d20 Modern?

Tags: d20-modern

Can I double tap (as per the feat) with a .44 magnum in d20 Modern?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The .44 magnum is listed as a semi-automatic weapon so, yes you can double tap if you meet the following pre-requisites:

1. Dex 13
2. Point Blank Shot feat
3. Double Tap feat
4. At least two bullets in your 44!

Comment: I'd say the semi-auto requirement is just to exclude single shot weapons that would need reloading between shots, which you can't of course double tap with! You can in real life double tap with a revolver, as you could with an M4 set to semi, but it'd be harder with something with no semi option, such as an M60, which is help up by the rules as written.

Answer (score 0):

The mechanics of a revolver are VERY different from the mechanics of a semi-auto pistol.  When fired, a semi-auto will fire the round, eject the spent cartridge, chamber a new round, and recock the hammer.

When a revolver fires, the gun returns to it's "safe" state.  The hammer is forward and  uncocked.  When one attempts to "double tap" the revolver, you need to pull the trigger so that the cylinder rotates, the hammer comes back and then fires.

Double tapping on a semi-auto is much easier as the trigger is in it's "hair trigger" position.

I'd say you should not be able to do it with a revolver.

Comment: +1 @Pulsehead for a great explanation of how the firearm works (We need you for the [firearms](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/164/firearms) stackexchange!).  It's not the way the rules read, but it would make a good house rule.  I can double tap a .38 revolver btw.

Comment: One CAN do 2 quick trigger pulls on a revolver.  The problem is that the force needed to pull that trigger the second time (and the first assuming it's not cocked beforehand) is an amount that the sight picture would be thrown off.  hence I'd houserule that you can't... or would take something like a +4-5 (in d20) penalty.  I think Shadowrun did it very well.  You could, but the penalty was +2, and that was on a handful of d6's

Comment: One of the biggest contentions about d20 Modern has always been how accurate their firearms rules are.  Personally I think they struck a good balance.  I do add house rules for realism when playing my friends who are soldiers and the like.  As far as the revolver double tap, whether the site picture change is enough to throw you off target depends on range, skill, etc.  The feat already has a -2 penalty, which I think is *close enough*.

Comment: Double-action revolvers double-tap the same way that DAO semi-autos do.  Also, there does exist at least one model of semi-automatic revolver of which I am aware. Ability to double-tap any weapon comes down to time to get the weapon back on target and time to cycle its operation again.  A DA revolver is not significantly different in this regard from a semi-auto. There will be a difference in accuracy for just pulling the trigger vs taking the time to cock the hammer, but that is a separate mechanic. Double-tapping with a .44mag OTOH... You'd need forearms like popeye to get it back on target.

Comment: @Perkins  Two semi-auto revolvers, at least.  The Webley-Forsberry, from around 1890, and the modern (2000s) Mateba (resembles a Chiappa Rhino; low-barrel revolver with sliding ratchet action similar to the Webley-Forsberry).

Answer (score -4):

Comes down to personal preference for realism versus action heroism.

My own preference is to be able to use double Tap for even single action revolvers, as even during Western times there were people who could cap off with an old thumb buster in seconds. As to whether or not these people could get those rounds off with any kind of accuracy, that comes down to fate and the roll of the dice. I do the same with pump and bolt action weapons, though the character sacrifices their move action to do it. All they do is cycle and shoot that turn.

I would have your character, be able to do it. Though you would be firmly planted and aiming with as much care as you could with that much stopping power recoiling in your hands. You would probably not want to akimbo that .44 and you would want to be pretty close.